# Was the biker bar scene from Terminator 2 filmed on the same night as the beating of Rodney King?

Tags: terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

Multiple reputable sources confirm that the biker bar scene at the beginning of *Terminator 2: Judgment Day* was filmed a few blocks away from where Rodney King was pulled over and beaten by police, and that George Holliday, the man who filmed the beating, shot footage of the filming of  this scene before the beating. James Cameron even confirms the link in [this LA Times article](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1991-07-02-ca-1810-story.html). There are multiple claims on the internet that this occurred on the same night, however I've found no confirmation of this. I've heard that Cameron also mentions it in some commentary, but I've never seen it.

Comment: Note that if it's on the same tape it's probably the same night; most pro-am videographers wouldn't have headed out with only part of a tape available to record on...

Comment: It is on the same tape. In fact, the article says that the beating and the T2 filming are the only things on the tape.

Comment: How is this important for appreciation of the movies? It sounds like something that should be asked on the [skeptics.se] site

Comment: I would think since you have a linked source directly from James Cameron, that would be confirmation enough.

Comment: @Luciano Meh.  I don't see anything wrong with this question on this site.  It is totally important for the appreciation of movies.  It's interesting, just like all of the legends surrounding _The Wizard of Oz_

Comment: @steelersquirrel The source doesn't say it was on the same night.

Comment: The rodney king tape has timecode datestamp - seems to be a consumer level camcorder, would be nice to see the bar footage with that on it. The interior bar footage was shot the year before and probably on a sound stage (?)

Comment: Its easy to have two different bits of footage from two dates on the same tape, especially when its mere minutes or seconds, i don't recall Holliday being some kind of pro level amateur, carefully separating footage, media in those days wasn't cheap. Afaik, this is an urban legend with the only truth bit being the location and that they're on the same tape, but not necessarily the same night. Even Cameron is not explicitly stating the same night IIRC

Comment: The camcorder was brand new. Pretty sure I remember reading somewhere that the T2 filming was the first thing he ever filmed with it.

Comment: Cool, be good to link anything you can in the question. I saw a red dit discussion on the same query, same result, not sure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's trivia and has nothing to do with movies or the understanding of them.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Trivia is accepted on this site now https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4901/were-retiring-the-trivia-close-reason

Comment: @blobbymcblobby Here is a link to an article where Holliday mentions it: https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/lifestyle/lifestyle-news/flashback-how-a-plumber-altered-history-by-taping-the-attack-on-rodney-king-4141644/. He doesn't state the date except that it was "before the beating". This one states it was filmed on March 2 around 10 pm: https://www.sealionpress.co.uk/post/how-james-cameron-led-to-the-la-riots I don't know where that information came from, but if this is true, the scene Holliday managed to tape may not have been the one used  in the film.

Comment: @Sagierian Thanks!  quite often internal and external scenes are shot at different times (and locations) so it could still have been used. The answer posted now is interesting!

Answer (score 7):

### No. There is "a week or so" gap

Cameron talks about it in the commentary to the film. He says that "apparently", the video of them shooting the scene was at the head of the tape — from "a week or so earlier" than the video of the beating.

Here is the excerpt:

https://soundcloud.com/user-691406483/james-cameron-talks-about-filming-the-bar-scene-in-t2